# XML Request with HttpClient throws Null Exception

Tags: java, http

```
try
{
  String xmlReq = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request_inquiry><partner_id>0999</ partner_id><terminal_type>6012</ terminal_ type><product_code>4001</product _code><date_time>20130715115100</date_time><trx_id>SDFSF11234424ADFA</trx_id><data><cust_id>030913320611</cust_id></data></request_inquiry>";

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout);
  httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, timeout);
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("202.169.43.53:52056/transaction");
  httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml;charset=ISO");
//      httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(xmlReq.length()));
  StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xmlReq, ContentType.TEXT_XML);
  httpPost.setEntity(se);
  System.out.println("Request>>"+httpPost);
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("");
  try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
      InputStream in =  httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
      byte b[] = new byte[1024] ;
      while(in.read(b) != -1) {
        html.append((new String(b)).toString());
        b = new byte[1024];
      }
      System.out.println("Output HTML>> "+html.toString());
    }
    else{
      InputStream in =  httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
      byte b[] = new byte[1024] ;
      while(in.read(b) != -1) {
        html.append((new String(b)).toString());
        b = new byte[1024];
      }
      System.out.println(html);
    }



  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new SystemException(Common.ERROR_OTHER, ex.getMessage());
  }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Exception>>"+ex.getMessage());
}
```

I've tried many ways to send XML request to server. and one of the way is look likes the code above. And I have no idea why throws NullException? Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks for help.

Comment: which line is throwing the exeception

Answer (score 0):

The actual exception is in the line

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("202.169.43.53:52056/transaction");
```

saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:841)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:76)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 202.169.43.53:52056/transaction
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2810)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2983)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:2993)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3009)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:577)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:839)
    ... 2 more
```

It is because the URI is missing the protocol like `http://` or `https://`

Ex:

```
try {
    String xmlReq = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request_inquiry><partner_id>0999</ partner_id><terminal_type>6012</ terminal_ type><product_code>4001</product _code><date_time>20130715115100</date_time><trx_id>SDFSF11234424ADFA</trx_id><data><cust_id>030913320611</cust_id></data></request_inquiry>";

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
            CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 30);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
            CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 30);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://202.169.43.53:52056/transaction");
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml;charset=ISO");
    // httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,
    // Integer.toString(xmlReq.length()));
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xmlReq, ContentType.TEXT_XML);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    System.out.println("Request>>" + httpPost);
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        byte b[] = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(b) != -1) {
            html.append((new String(b)).toString());
            b = new byte[1024];
        }
        System.out.println("Output HTML>> " + html.toString());
    } else {
        InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        byte b[] = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(b) != -1) {
            html.append((new String(b)).toString());
            b = new byte[1024];
        }
        System.out.println(html);
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Note: When you are logging exceptions make sure you log the stack trace as well, since it will give you more details about the exception like which class, method and line caused the exception.*